# Facebook webhook to Node-RED

Tags: ibm-cloud

I want to verify a Facebook webhook to Node-RED. The node details in the course do not match those in Bluemix Node-RED.

**[Course](https://developer.ibm.com/courses/all/node-red-basics-bots/?course=begin#4084):**

[image]

**Bluemix Node-RED:**

[image]

Am I using the wrong Node-RED node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The top picture shows a debug node, the bottom picture shows a http response node, which one does the course at the point you are, ask you to use?

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the attached, just paste a url like: /chatbot, then paste it on webhook(https://yourdomain.mybluemix.net/chatbot) and it works[image]